# Choosing the two biggest pairs in a yatzhee game

Tags: vb.net

So hello again, I were wondering how we could get 2 of the biggest pairs in a yatzee game.
From a previous question i got help by finding one pair but now i dont even know. It would seem we just need to double the amount in the 1 pair code, but doing that i just got no result or just x4 of the dice

```
   Public Function parVerdier1(ByVal regel As Integer, tall As Object)
    Dim sum As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        For j As Integer = (i + 1) To 4
            If tall(i) = tall(j) Then
                If tall(i) + tall(j) > sum Then
                    sum = tall(i) + tall(j)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return sum
End Function
```

This is the 1 pair code if ayone were wondering, help pls and thank you :)
Also the `regel` is used futher down the rest of the code.

yatzee is a game where you throw 5 dices, the eyes = points (you can combo it for more points etc). lets pretend you threw (3 3 4 4 5), by selecting it as a pair you get 8points (4+4), if you select it as two pairs you get 14points (4+4+3+3)  you can read more here if you want to learn all the rules http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee  its a pretty easy game and fun to play if you're bored.

My lates code with a lot of help thank you :) still got some problems like http://imgur.com/ExpBb2Q when i get these dices i get 40 points...

```
    Public Function parVerdier2(ByVal regel As Integer, tall As Object)

    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim sum2 As Integer = 0
    For o As Integer = 0 To 4
        For l As Integer = (o + 1) To 4
            For i As Integer = (l + 1) To 4
                For j As Integer = (i + 1) To 4
                    If tall(i) = tall(j) And tall(o) = tall(l) Or tall(i) = tall(o) And tall(j) = tall(l) Or tall(i) = tall(l) And tall(j) = tall(o) Then
                        If tall(i) + tall(j) + tall(o) + tall(l) > sum Then
                            sum2 = sum
                            sum = tall(i) + tall(j) + tall(o) + tall(l)
                        ElseIf tall(i) + tall(j) + tall(o) + tall(l) > sum2 Then
                            sum2 = tall(i) + tall(j) + tall(o) + tall(l)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
    sum += sum2
    Return sum
 End Function
```

Comment: why the tag spam?  this appears to have nothing to do with VBA or with VisualStudio

Comment: isnt microsoft visual studio= vb.net? whoops I'm sry then :(

Comment: For those not familiar with yatzee game, could you please explain in your question?

Comment: ok wrote a short description about the game

Comment: I would ask in your previous question, but what is that unused `regel` in your parameters?

Comment: its used for a code further down

Comment: I would suggest you enable Option Strict On. Passing "tall" as an Object seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

you would just need another variable for the second biggest sum:

```
Public Function parVerdier1(ByVal regel As Integer, tall As Object)

    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim sum2 As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        For j As Integer = (i + 1) To 4
            If tall(i) = tall(j) Then
                If tall(i) + tall(j) > sum Then
                    sum2 = sum
                    sum = tall(i) + tall(j)
                Else If tall(i) + tall(j) > sum2 Then
                    sum2 = tall(i) + tall(j)
                End If 

            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return sum + sum2
End Function
```

Comment: hmm ok so i tried this out but doesnt seem to give the right result I got these dices http://imgur.com/Z1my1VH (3 4 3 4 2) by selecting 2 pairs i should get (3+3 + 4+4) = 14 points but instead i get 8 points (4+4). Sry for the late reply my network decided to not work

Comment: @bcil Seems like you just copy/pasted to code... This returns just sum but you want both sum and sum2 added together.

Comment: ye i've been playing with the code, maybe i forgot to add both together

Comment: so yea when its two pairs its added corretly, but when its 1pair its still added to the points (3 4 4 5 2) if i select 2pairs 8points(4+4) is added. Sry for all these questions, I'm still a beginner with vb and I'm trying to learn it... Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to get the two pairs with the greatest sum:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim dieValues() As Integer = {3, 3, 4, 4, 5}

    Dim pairs = dieValues.GroupBy(Function(i) i).
                          Where(Function(g) g.Count() = 2).
                          OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.Sum()).
                          Select(Function(g) New With {.Value = g.Key, .Sum = g.Sum()}).
                          Take(2)


    For Each g In pairs
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", g.Key, g.Sum)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Output:

```
4: 8
3: 6
```